# MySQL along with row transpose in multiple table Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql Database, I have 1 Master table and 2 supporting tables(Normalized), I have one

more table - Additional Table which has Attribute(Key) and Value stored in multiple rows. I have to

Join Master, Supporting and Additional table now along with additional tables rows to be transposed

to column

```
MASTER TABLE - tbl_student
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | Stud_Name |  Stud_Class |
+----+-----------+-------------+
|  1 |  abc      |           6 |
|  2 |  def      |           6 |
+----+-----------+-------------+


SUPPORTING TABLE 1 - tbl_student_address
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+----------+
| id | Stud_id |  Address1 |  Address2 |  City |  State |  Country |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |  abcdef   |  defgh    |    16 |     20 |      102 |
|  2 |       2 |  xyz      |  ijk      |    16 |     20 |      102 |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------+----------+

SUPPORTING TABLE 2 - tbl_parent_info
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+
| id |  Stud_id |  Parent_email1 |  Parent_email2 |
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+
|  1 |        1 |  zyx@gmail.com |  abc@yahoo.com |
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+

ADDITIONAL TABLE - tbl_marks
+----+----------+-------------+--------+
| id |  Stud_id |  Subject_id |  marks |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |          10 |     45 |
|  2 |        1 |          11 |     43 |
|  3 |        1 |          12 |     50 |
|  4 |        2 |          10 |     50 |
|  5 |        2 |          11 |     49 |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+
```

I need below Structure

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | Stud_id | Stud_Name | Stud_Class | Parent_email1 | Parent_email2 | Subject_id (01) | marks | Subject_id (02) | marks (02) | Subject_id (03) | marks (03)  |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | abc       |          6 | zyx@gmail.com | abc@yahoo.com |              10 |    45 |              11 |         43 |              12 |          50 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: you should update your question add a proper data sample and the expcted  result  ...

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Yes I can handle it in my Appln Layer(Controller) before i pass the details to Views. But If i can get this through MySQL it would be a great help.. I was going through PIVOT in SQL but i didnt get anything in MySQL like that... Anywasys i will do lil bit of RnD and if i get it will post the Answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tbl_student` as base of a `LEFT JOIN` and perform `SUM` operation on the `tbl_marks` then `GROUP BY tbl_student.id`. Below example query:

```
SELECT     tbl_student.id, tbl_parent_info.Stud_id, tbl_student.stud_Name, tbl_student.Stud_Class,
           tbl_parent_info.Parent_email1, tbl_parent_info.Parent_email2,
           SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_marks.subject_id=10 THEN tbl_marks.subject_id END) AS 'Subject_id(01)',
           SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_marks.subject_id=10 THEN tbl_marks.marks END) AS 'marks(01)',
           SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_marks.subject_id=11 THEN tbl_marks.subject_id END) AS 'Subject_id(02)',
           SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_marks.subject_id=11 THEN tbl_marks.marks END) AS 'marks(02)',
           SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_marks.subject_id=12 THEN tbl_marks.subject_id END) AS 'Subject_id(03)',
           SUM(CASE WHEN tbl_marks.subject_id=12 THEN tbl_marks.marks END) AS 'marks(03)'  
FROM       tbl_student 
LEFT JOIN  tbl_parent_info ON tbl_student.id=tbl_parent_info.stud_id
LEFT JOIN  tbl_marks ON tbl_student.id=tbl_marks.stud_id
GROUP BY   tbl_student.id;
```

Note that I skipped `tbl_student_address` in this query example because I didn't see it being used in the expected output.

Or if the above query example is too much happening in the `SELECT`, you can do a `LEFT JOIN` three times on `tbl_marks` as a sub-query whereby each sub-query with specific `subject_id` in `WHERE` condition. Below example:

```
SELECT     tbl_student.id, tbl_parent_info.Stud_id, tbl_student.stud_Name, tbl_student.Stud_Class,
           tbl_parent_info.Parent_email1, tbl_parent_info.Parent_email2,
           tm_1.subject_id AS 'Subject_id(01)', tm_1.marks AS 'marks(01)',
           tm_2.subject_id AS 'Subject_id(02)', tm_2.marks AS 'marks(02)',
           tm_3.subject_id AS 'Subject_id(03)', tm_3.marks AS 'marks(03)'
FROM       tbl_student 
LEFT JOIN  tbl_parent_info ON tbl_student.id=tbl_parent_info.stud_id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT stud_id,subject_id,marks FROM tbl_marks WHERE subject_id=10) tm_1 ON tbl_student.id=tm_1.stud_id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT stud_id,subject_id,marks FROM tbl_marks WHERE subject_id=11) tm_2 ON tbl_student.id=tm_2.stud_id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT stud_id,subject_id,marks FROM tbl_marks WHERE subject_id=12) tm_3 ON tbl_student.id=tm_3.stud_id
GROUP BY   tbl_student.id;
```

The second example might not be the best option if you have a lot of subjects though.

Comment: Thx a Ton @tcadidot0. CASE WHEN THEN seems to do the trick... Now I am trying to generalize the query.

Comment: Glad I could help @deeflor